# How to disable other checkboxes in an inflatedview

Tags: android

I have an linearlayout1 in an activity, also I have another layout2 with TextBox and checkbox.

So layout2 is inflated and added to layout1, which is done multiple times. After the complete inflation I get a kind of listView which has TextView and checkbox.
Now I have the requirement to make the checkbox behave like Radiobutton,means if one of the chekbox is clicked others should be disabled.
I did some googling and made something, but everytime when I click one box the complete layout is disabled.

Can anyone please tell me how to handle this.

Comment: Perhaps if you put for every inflated layout2 the result of something like `layout2.findViewById(R.id.idofcheckbox)` in a list. Now you have have to add an onClickListener on each of them that disables all other checkboxes in the list.

Comment: I suggest actually using a ListView and `android:choiceMode="single"`. This will create the single choice, radio button effect automatically.

Comment: Sam: I cant use the listview becuase this layout I have to use in an ScrollView..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use ScrollView, then try to change it to ListView and the other View, that needs to be scrolled as well as list, add as a ListView's header:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)